# Parsing date in java

Tags: java

I am trying to parse this "06th Oct 2013" date using java.

```
String[] formatStrings = {"dd MMM yyyy","dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm"};
    public Date tryParse(String dateString)
    {
        for (String formatString : formatStrings)
        {
            try
            {
                return new SimpleDateFormat(formatString).parse(dateString);
            }
            catch (ParseException e) {}
        }

        return null;
    }
```

I tried "ddth MMM yyyy" too it was not working.

Any idea to parse it.

**Answer:**

use quotes for string.

`"dd'th' MMM yyyy"`

Comment: Remove `th` and try with your date pattern

Comment: quoting 'th' wont work for 1st 2nd 21st 22nd etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can use DateUtils, with Dateutils you can code as:

```
String str = "06th Oct 2013";
String[] strArrFormat = {"dd'st' MMM yyyy","dd'nd' MMM  yyyy","dd'th' MMM  yyyy","dd'rd' MMM yyyy"};
DateUtils tmpDU = new DateUtils();
System.out.print("" + tmpDU.parseDate(str,strArrFormat));
```

**See also:**

- [DateUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just add to your `formatStrings` following pattern `"dd'th' MMM yyyy"`. Well, but it won't solve problem with date like `01st Oct 2013` and `02nd Oct 2013`. You can add `"dd'st' MMM yyyy"` and so one, but isn't elegant.

I'll will update this post when I solve it.

---

**UPDATE**
This would be best for me:

```
  String[] formatStrings = {"dd MMM yyyy","dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm"};
  String[] forbiddenStrings = {"st","nd","rd","th"};
  public Date tryParse(String dateString)
  {
    for(String remove : forbiddenStrings) {
      dateString = dateString.replaceAll(remove,"");
    }

    for (String formatString : formatStrings)
    {
      try
      {
        return new SimpleDateFormat(formatString).parse(dateString);
      }
      catch (ParseException e) {}
    }

    return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String date =  "06th Oct 2013";
date = date.substring(0,2) + date.substring(4);
```

That will remove the th or whatever characters in the date that's impeding the parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Use below format along with Locale if needed

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd'th' MMM YYYY");
```